# Unity3D Build Configuration for Deployment/ Publish

Tags: unity, mobile, publishing, appstore, build-process

Is there the option within Unity3D to specify build configurations?

My goal is relatively simple - when building for mobile stores (Play Store/ App Store) I want to make sure my app is pointing to the production services, rather than the test one I use in the editor/ testing on devices.

It's controlled by a field on a `MonoBehaviour` currently, but we I need to remember to flip it from `Test` to `Production` before doing a build and publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's build system is very scriptable, would have a look at their [Build Player Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) docs, and [BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html)

You can use the sample code the provide as a base for creating menu items you select that initiate builds with a specific configurations.  I would use this in conjunction with Scripting Define Symbols that to define DEV_BUILD or PRODUCTION_BUILD so you can use preprocessor checks wherever they're needed.

For example, this would create a menu item for initiating a Development iOS build -- could set a method for each platform / target:

```
public class MyBuildController 
{
    [MenuItem("Build/iOS Dev")]
    public static void BuildiOSDev()
    {
        // setup basic build options (scenes, platform, target directory)
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scene1.unity", "Assets/Scene2.unity" };
        buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "iOSBuild";
        buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.iOS;
        buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;

        // set scripting define symbols so can use conditional compilation for things that target Dev / Production
        PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup( BuildTargetGroup.iOS, "DEV_BUILD" );

        // start build
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
    }
}
```

Your code can then use conditional compilation to include or exclude code that should run when targeting a dev build:

```
#if DEV_BUILD
Debug.Log( "Hi from Dev Build" );
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this article might have some answers for you https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Simply check what platform you're on and set the production service accordingly.
Works the same in both C# and JavaScript.

```
var envi = test

#if UNITY_IOS
  envi = ios
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
  envi = android
#endif
```

You can also make a development build (checkmark in the build menu) and use the `Debug.isDebugBuild` to check if the current build is a development build
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug-isDebugBuild.html

```
var envi = prod
if (Debug.isDebugBuild) {
  envi = test
}
```

Comment: I believe you should be able to write `#if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID` if you wish to check for both just like a regular `if()` but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks @HappyGuyDK. That's not quite what I was after. For example, I'm building for Android right now, but need it pointing at the test environment.

Comment: I might have misunderstood you. I edited my answer with another example which I'm assuming was the answer you were actually looking for?